# Redis implementation in java

Tags: java, data-structures, redis, hashmap, skip-lists

I am trying to implement a basic **redis server** in java. But I am not sure of what *data structures* I must use to implement its database. First I thought simple `HashMap` is enough, as it can store `<Object, Object>` values, and I could implement `GET` and `SET` commands. But when I went deeply I could find commands like `GETBIT`, `SETBIT` , `ZADD` etc. which require a more complicated data structure for the database.

> I think I should use a HashMap with value column of type ConcurrentSkipListMap. Am I right? Please help.

*And also, should I store String values of Set command after converting it into its binary value?*

Answer (score 1):

Implementing a full blown `Java` clone of `redis` (or even a `redis` client) is not a simple task and will definitely not fit in a SO answer.

The good news is, you don't need to: There's a number of [redis Java clients](http://redis.io/clients#java) you can use. Alternatively, you may explore the code of any one of those clients and get an idea of what you'd need in order to implement one yourself.

Comment: I just need to know what data structures are use in redis sever.

Comment: The first Google result for *redis data structures* will give you a [list of all data structures in redis](http://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro). However, how you choose to implement them in Java is up to you.

Comment: What I mean is in what data structure format the data will be stored in the rdb file and also in the in- memory state.

Answer (score 1):

The [redis-protocol](https://github.com/spullara/redis-protocol) project has

> netty4-server/
>     A very high performance in-JVM memory redis server clone

which you may find useful as a reference. It seems the author mostly keeps data structures in the [util](https://github.com/spullara/redis-protocol/tree/master/util/src/main/java/redis/util) directory; those are what you'll want to look at.

These data structures are of course only the in-memory versions, but for a simple persistence implementation you might start by serializing all your in-memory structures to a file, unless you want the file to be readable by the real Redis, serialization format shouldn't matter.